# Git repository with branched submodules gets errors when cloning recursively

Tags: git, github

I have a git repository that contains submodules to specific branches of other repositories. I'm making addons for the Godot game engine, and I'm using git submodules and branches as a makeshift package system, with a github action that publishes my addon to its own release branch in the repository. I can then use the release branch as a submodule for other addons, projects, etc.

However, I ran into an issue creating a submodule of an addon that uses another addon. Here's the layout of my submodule dependencies.

```
FixedGodotVolatilePhysicsRollback
|-> FracturalCommons
'-> FixedGodotVolatilePhysics
   '-> FracturalCommons
```

When I clone the repository recursively, I ultimately get an error:

```bash
 git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/Fractural/GodotFixedVolatilePhysicsRollback.git
Cloning into 'GodotFixedVolatilePhysicsRollback'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 493, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (493/493), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (291/291), done.
remote: Total 493 (delta 185), reused 493 (delta 185), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (493/493), 2.24 MiB | 11.94 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (185/185), done.
Submodule 'addons/FracturalCommons' (https://github.com/Fractural/FracturalCommons.git) registered for path 'addons/FracturalCommons'
Submodule 'addons/GodotFixedVolatilePhysics' (https://github.com/Fractural/GodotFixedVolatilePhysics.git) registered for path 'addons/GodotFixedVolatilePhysics'
Submodule 'addons/GodotRollbackNetcodeMono' (https://github.com/Fractural/GodotRollbackNetcodeMono.git) registered for path 'addons/GodotRollbackNetcodeMono'
Submodule 'addons/godot-rollback-netcode' (https://github.com/Fractural/GodotRollbackNetcodeMono.git) registered for path 'addons/godot-rollback-netcode'`
Cloning into 'C:/Location/GodotFixedVolatilePhysicsRollback/addons/FracturalCommons'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1157, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (328/328), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (225/225), done.
remote: Total 1157 (delta 150), reused 273 (delta 100), pack-reused 829
Receiving objects: 100% (1157/1157), 2.62 MiB | 8.59 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (571/571), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Location/GodotFixedVolatilePhysicsRollback/addons/GodotFixedVolatilePhysics'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1400, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (458/458), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (285/285), done.
remote: Total 1400 (delta 275), reused 308 (delta 159), pack-reused 942
Receiving objects: 100% (1400/1400), 70.60 MiB | 15.96 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (764/764), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Location/GodotFixedVolatilePhysicsRollback/addons/GodotRollbackNetcodeMono'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 187, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (187/187), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (144/144), done.
remote: Total 187 (delta 51), reused 169 (delta 33), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (187/187), 421.51 KiB | 5.94 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (51/51), done.
Cloning into 'C:/Location/GodotFixedVolatilePhysicsRollback/addons/godot-rollback-netcode'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 187, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (187/187), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (144/144), done.
remote: Total 187 (delta 51), reused 169 (delta 33), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (187/187), 421.51 KiB | 7.81 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (51/51), done.
Submodule path 'addons/FracturalCommons': checked out 'ba68b154508ff4239fd864ceb6c81bb899e44936'
Submodule path 'addons/GodotFixedVolatilePhysics': checked out '7293bbf098bd1613c47f0377d5d753a5611ee24b'
fatal: No url found for submodule path 'addons/GodotFixedVolatilePhysics/addons/FracturalCommons' in .gitmodules
fatal: Failed to recurse into submodule path 'addons/GodotFixedVolatilePhysics'
```

Since I'm pulling from the release branch, there shouldn't be a need to recurse through submodules of `FixedGodotVolatilePhysics`, since the release branches contain no .gitmodules file and only contains the addon's folder. Is there any way to get avoid this error when cloning the repository with submodules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current solution is to do

```
git clone https://github.com/Fractural/GodotFixedVolatilePhysicsRollback.git
cd GodotFixedVolatilePhysicsRollback
git submodule update --init
```

which seems to work by only initializing the repository's immediate submodules (hence avoiding trying to load nested submodules). If anyone finds a better solution please let me know!

Comment: I'm facing the same issues. However, despite the errors the cloned repo seems to be fully populated including the submodules. Is this what you see as well ?

Comment: I don't believe I encountered that issue. I know I have a pretty niche use-case since I'm loading a branch as a submodule, and the branch doesn't use the main branch's nested submodules at all. If you need to load the nested submodules then I unfortunately don't have a solution. :(